# Spring boot application authenticating user by physical presence at the server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am working on a Spring boot application and have received a requirement where a certain endpoint must be accessible only by authorized users that too the user must be present physically at the system serving the app. An optional case is the user could also be able to access the endpoint if the user has SSH access to the server. This makes me think that some sort of key (a file or a program) can be used to unlock the endpoint. Not being a person proficient in security, this has put me at a loss on how to implement such a feature using Spring Boot. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Spring boot doesn't have built in support for this scenario, but what you actually need is **PAM** (Linux Pluggable Authentication Modules) port for java ([JPam](http://jpam.sourceforge.net/) can be a good solution).

You can write your own AuthenticationProvider for spring security which will do something like this in it's validation method:

```
Pam pam = new Pam();
boolean authenticated = pam.authenticateSuccessful(username, password));
```

This library is good enough documented ([pdf](http://jpam.sourceforge.net/JPamUserGuide.pdf))

Another PAM for java solution can be found [here libpam4j](https://github.com/kohsuke/libpam4j)